# Conflicting types - although they are the same (T4 - Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll)

Tags: c#, .net, t4, smo

I have a T4 template in a client project that uses code compiled in a DLL. This code is using `Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll`. There is a reference in T4 code to `Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll` I use in the project.

But I get the following error:

> [A]Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.TableCollection cannot be cast to 
>      [B]Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.TableCollection. 
>      Type A originates from 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=14.100.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLCommon\140\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll'. 
>      Type B originates from 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=14.100.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' in the context 'LoadFrom' at location 'C:\Users\B1020\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\XJJV34RM.TT9\X8C5DCTR.DVJ\0598d01b\00e07435_080cd301\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll'.

My T4 template:

```
<#@ assembly name="E:\Projects\DragonFly\CodeGenerator\bin\Debug\Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="E:\Projects\DragonFly\CodeGenerator\bin\Debug\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="E:\Projects\DragonFly\CodeGenerator\bin\Debug\Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="E:\Projects\DragonFly\CodeGenerator\bin\Debug\Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="E:\Projects\DragonFly\CodeGenerator\bin\Debug\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="E:\Projects\DragonFly\CodeGenerator\bin\Debug\CodeGenerator.dll" #>
```

I'm trying to cast the following from type object:

```
var tables = (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.TableCollection)otables;
```

This is where the exception occurs.

Comment: The problem may be that you are trying to cast among the types with the same name but are at different locations.

Comment: Do you have that smo.dll added as reference in your T4 project?

Comment: @NoSaidTheCompiler Not really because they are originating from the same dll-file. But the codegenerator places it in the AppData folders. I will try to use reflection to load the types from the same dll.

Comment: @RossBush No, I don't want that.

Comment: Then how does it get to your debug/bin folder during a build?

Comment: I copied all the code of my dll to a included T4 template. Not ideal for me, but it works now.